# Creating a data frame from split shuffled CSV file to match original CSV file, then calculate the sums to match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two CSV files that have been split from an original CSV file and the rows have been shuffled. I'd like to merge the two split files into one to match the original so I can perform calculations. The thing is, when I calculate the sum of the sales_amount column from the original, it doesn't match the sum from the two merged files' sales_amount column. I'm guessing the rows from the merged CSV file doesn't match the original, thus the summation will be wrong? I thought it wouldn't matter though using Pandas's groupby feature.

The orignal CSV has columns:

- pencil_mode
- sale_date
- pencil_brand
- sales_amount

The split CSV files have columns:

- First File:

  - pencil_mode
  - sale_date
- Second File:

  - pencil_brand
  - sales_amount

... with rows shuffled.

Below is what I thought would merge the two files and create a perfect match but since the rows are shuffled I can't seem to calculate the right matching sales amount from the original CSV.

```
df0 = pd.read_csv("sales_original.csv")
df1 = pd.read_csv("sales_split_1.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("sales_split_2.csv")
df2_join = df2[["pencil_brand", "sales_amount"]]
df3 = df1.join(df2_join)
```

When I input the command

```
df0.groupby("pencil_model").sum()
df3.groupby("pencil_model").sum()
```

I get complete different sums for each pencil model.

I apologize if I'm missing something. It's my first time posting here. I can try my best to replicate the code. I'm a complete novice to Python as well.

Comment: in order for you to be able to merge two split dataframes correctly, either you need to have shuffled indices from original indices, or some key that can correspond split rows together (maybe a common column or index). Otherwise, I do not see how you can match the rows of split data frames without any information.

Comment: Oh I see! I'll try to join them with a common column. I think I just joined them without specifying that, so it's probably merging them a default way somehow.